# Remove item from second dropdown based on selection in First using Javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have four dropdown, and I am manually filling them.

Now I want to add a javacsript that when I select first dropdown option, then in the second third fourth dropdowns, that item or option can be removed.

And same flow goes for second third and fourth and so on.

I am giving my code but till now, it is not working fine.

I am only tring for the first ladder, that is when option in first is selected then item removed from second, third and fourth dropdowns.

```
 function RemoveItems(){
     var List1 = document.getElementById("ddlSortField");
     var sortList1 = List1.options[List1.selectedIndex].text;

     var List2 = document.getElementById("ddlSortField2");
     var sortList2 = List2.options[List2.selectedIndex].text;
     List2.options.remove(sortList1);

     var List3 = document.getElementById("ddlSortField3");
     var sortList3 = List3.options[List3.selectedIndex].text;
     List3.options.remove(sortList2);

     var List4 = document.getElementById("ddlSortField4");
     var sortList4 = List4.options[List4.selectedIndex].text;
     List4.options.remove(sortList3);
}
```

Comment: I'll gladly help out if you paste your code in a jsfiddle or jsbin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
> function RemoveItems(){
```

Variable names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors, so:

```
function removeItems() {

>     var List1 = document.getElementById("ddlSortField");
>     var sortList1 = List1.options[List1.selectedIndex].text;
```

So *sortList1* will be a string.

```
>     var List2 = document.getElementById("ddlSortField2");
>     var sortList2 = List2.options[List2.selectedIndex].text;
>     List2.options.remove(sortList1);
```

The [*remove*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-33404570) method of the *options* collection takes a single parameter that is an index of one of the options. You have not shown what the value of *sortList1* nor how many options *List2* has. Note that the options collection is live, so if you remove an option, the indexes of other options may be adjusted so that they are contiguous from 0 to `options.length - 1`.

Comment: This is what I am doing exactly and the same reason is there. What can be the way to avoid the contagious value problem?

Comment: Don't use indexes to reference options between select elements, use the value or text some other attribute or property that is more suited to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to remove option

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ddlSortField').change(function(){
        var index = $("#ddlSortField option:selected").val();

        $('#ddlSortField2 option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
        $('#ddlSortField3 option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
        $('#ddlSortField4 option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
 });
});
```

Note in your html your option value must be same like this:

```
<select id="ddlSortField">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlSortField1">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use such code : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AhXqw/).

Basically, you first bind the `change` event to each list and when you change the value you hide these elements in all lists after...

Comment: No its not working as I have a two scripts running on the same event and that is freezing all.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a slightly different one than @Muhammad Omair's, this one is a bit more dynamic. **Note that this is jQuery**

```
var removeSelection = function(select) {
    $('select').filter(':not(#' + select.attr('id') + ')').each(function() {
        var index = select.find(':selected').index();
        $(this).find('option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        removeSelection($(this));
    });
});
```

And here's a jsfiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/cA3F9/